# How to get field name dynamically in oracle pl/sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table that contains fields named 'value1','value2', 'value3'.
In sql code I have a variable selectedValue of type NUMBER that gets its value dynamically inside loop in code. Also I have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT value1 FROM val_table;
```

So I want to select value1 when selectedValue = 1, value2 when selectedValue = 2, value3 when selectedValue = 3.

How can I get field name dynamically in SELECT statement depending on value of selectedValue variable?

Comment: Please edit your question and show both sample data and the code you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be:

```
DECLARE
  aNumber  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  CASE selectedValue
    WHEN 1 THEN SELECT VALUE1 INTO aNumber FROM VAL_TABLE;
    WHEN 2 THEN SELECT VALUE2 INTO aNumber FROM VAL_TABLE;
    WHEN 3 THEN SELECT VALUE3 INTO aNumber FROM VAL_TABLE;
  END CASE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('aNumber=' || aNumber);
END;
```

If you want to make it more complicated you can do something like the following:

```
DECLARE
  aCursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  strQuery VARCHAR2(1000);
  strField VARCHAR2(20);
  aNumber  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  CASE selectedValue
    WHEN 1 THEN strField := 'VALUE1';
    WHEN 2 THEN strField := 'VALUE2';
    WHEN 3 THEN strField := 'VALUE3';
  END CASE;

  strQuery := 'SELECT ' || strField || ' FROM VAL_TABLE';

  OPEN aCursor FOR strQuery;

  LOOP
    FETCH aCursor INTO aNumber;
    EXIT WHEN aCursor%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('aNumber=' || aNumber);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE aCursor;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Also you can use DECODE() function instead of multiple WHEN ... THEN statements inside CASE

Comment: @denied - personally I prefer `CASE` over `DECODE`. YMMV.